# Liferay Tags page hangs

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

After upgrading server to Liferay 6.2, tags start to hang:

[image]

Tags autocomplete and tags editing also don't work.

How to fix?

Comment: Have you checked the [Liferay Issue Tracking System](https://issues.liferay.com/)? Most times such a problem comes from permission problems, which would result in a 403 as result of the AJAX request - you can check this with the network connections screen of your browser.

Comment: I have not found any problems like this in Liferay 6.2 CE GA4 and 6.2 EE GA1. what version are you using? Also check through firebug in firefox or web-developer tools in chrome whether there is a JS error or may be a network error for the request.